# In generate an Excel with DataTable I see : "A column named already belongs to this DataTable"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, datatable

I want to generate an Excel file and I am using Reflection to Fill DataTable,this is my code:

```
   private static DataTable CreateDataTable(PropertyInfo[] properties)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = null;
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            DisplayNameAttribute attr = (DisplayNameAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(pi, typeof(DisplayNameAttribute));
            dt.Columns.Add(attr.ToString(), pi.PropertyType);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

and my Class and attribute is:

```
    public class ACustomerLadgerAccount
{
    [DisplayName("qqq")]
    public string DocDateSolar { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("fff")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("ggg")]
    public decimal Credit { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("hhh")]
    public decimal Debit { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("yyy")]
    public decimal Remain { get; set; }
 }
```

But after insert first column in DataTable , I see this error:

```
A column named 'System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute' already belongs to this   DataTable.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must to use :

```
dt.Columns.Add(attr.DisplayName, pi.PropertyType);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
dt.Columns.Add(attr.DisplayName, pi.PropertyType);
```